# Encode String/NSString to Code Page 850 Format

Tags: ios, swift3, character-encoding

I need to encode a regular string (String or NSString) to a [Code Page 850 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).

There's an external String enconding who supports this format (It's called dosLatin1 in the [CFStringEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/cfstring/external_string_encodings) enum). I don't know if it's can really do the work, but it's the only reference that I found to Code Page 850 in the whole iOS documentation.

How can I use the CFStringEnconding to convert a "regular" string to a string at a CP850 format? Is it the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get by with CP 1252 which is the "modern" replacement for 850, then you can use Swift String's built in conversion. Otherwise, you can try using Core Foundation's conversion method.

```
let swiftString = "This is a string"

// Easy way -- use Swift String plus "modern" CP 1252 eoncding to get a block of data. Note: does not include BOM
if let data = swiftString.data(using: .windowsCP1252, allowLossyConversion: true) {
    print(data) // Do something with the resulting data
}

// The more thorough way to use CP 850 (enum value = 1040) -- use Core Foundation. This will produce a BOM if necessary.
let coreFoundationString = swiftString as CFString
let count = CFStringGetLength(coreFoundationString) * 2
var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)
let resultCount = CFStringGetBytes(coreFoundationString as CFString, CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(coreFoundationString)), 1040, 0x41, true, &buffer, count, nil)
print(buffer)
```